# How can I transform a 2d midjourney image in to a 3d model?

Tags: image, 3d, 3d-model

So,
I am generating beautiful architectural images using the new AI tool: Midjourney. But for a school project I need to find a process of transforming this images in to 3d models that I can create using a 3d printer. Any ideas?

I tried to use Rhino or Blender to trace the image but is a very hard process and usually not so accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it may be done with photogrametry by creating images in diferrent direction views and improting to photogrametry softwares like meshroom that make it to 3d object , if you test it
please share with me your experience thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding Midjourney is not able to create images with consistent scenes, this means that it'll be hard to create a 3d scene from inconsistent images.

further to @masia's answer, check out this low-code photogrammetry tool:
https://alicevision.org/#meshroom

You might want to check out NeRF as a machine learning based method for scene reconstruction: https://datagen.tech/guides/synthetic-data/neural-radiance-field-nerf/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33998463)